# GitHub Webhook Not Sending Messages for Changes in Projects Tab to my Discord Channel

Tags: github, discord, webhooks, github-webhook

This problem is probably best suited for the devs at GitHub but I'll post it here anyway for others with the same issue.

The GitHub Webhook works just fine on Discord sending notifications about any changes in the **repos** but any changes to the **Projects** tab does not get updated to Discord via the Webhook.

Comment: I have the same issue here, any updates?

Comment: We'd probably have to have the GitHub team add this functionality.

Comment: Still doesn't work, even if you manually select the project events in the webhook settings. Looks like it's on Discord's end though. If you check recent deliveries in the webhook settings it shows the project event payloads being sent properly. The response code from Discord is `204` but it doesn't show up in the messages.